# sql distinct or group by to get correct order

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, distinct, coalesce

Okay, so i have a list of posts and some posts are replies to other posts. I'd like to get a list of post parents in reverse order of replies.

I've tried group by but it always lists the wrong order and distinct is the only way i've managed to get it to work but obviously then it only lists the post id and not the rest of the data.

example of database here

[image]

The order i want to pull the posts out in is 1,3,5,4,2 These are the non-reply posts in the order of the latest reply.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `thread`
FROM
(
    SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(`parent_post`, 0), `postID`) AS `thread`
    FROM `posts`
    ORDER BY `postID` DESC
    LIMIT 100
) `sub`
```

This pulls them out in the correct order but obviously only pulls out the postID and not the rest of the fields, i've tried group by but it loses the correct order.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Why are you sorting by `postID` if you're looking for the latest reply? Shouldn't you be using `datetime`?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? presumably MySQL?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 - Raspbian 9.0

Comment: @melpomene, i don't want to pull out the replies, i want to pull out the ones that aren't replies to anything in the order that they've had replies. So post 7 is the latest one, but it's a reply to post 1 so i'd pull that one out first.

Comment: @Jezzzz Yes, that's what I'm saying. How did you determine that post 7 is the latest one?

Comment: It's the primary key, auto increment.

Comment: @Jezzzz That doesn't mean the row with the highest ID is the latest reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward translation of your requirements to SQL would be:

```
select *
from posts p1
where parent_post = 0
order by (
  select max("datetime")
  from posts p2
  where p2.parent_post = p1.postID
) desc
```

I.e. select all rows from `posts` that are thread starters (not replies) and order them by the latest timestamp from any of their replies in descending order.

Comment: Remove the double quotes from max(datetime) and yes this works. many thanks.

Comment: Oh, right. You have to [`set SQL_MODE = 'ANSI_QUOTES'`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/#sql_mode-values) to get MySQL/MariaDB to behave regarding quotes.